# Using X4R package in R to connect to a SSAS cube?

Tags: r, ssas, olap-cube

I am trying to figure out how to use `X4R` package to load a cube into R workspace. My server name is `"//vmtest//xmla2//msmdpump.dll""` and the cube name is `"Ocube_MANMartCube"`.

I couldn't find a way to connect to cube yet. I tried the following code:

```
library(X4R)
handle<-xmlaConnect(url="//vmtest//xmla2//msmdpump.dll"")
```

The message I am getting is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Header><BeginSession xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1"></BeginSession></Header><Body><Execute xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis"><Command><Statement></Statement></Command><Properties><PropertyList></PropertyList></Properties></Execute></Body></Envelope>`.

With the above output, R becomes busy and non-responsive. I am sure I have user access & I can connect to cube using Excel.

Am I doing everything right? There isn't any examples in the internet to go with. Probably someone who is familiar with the package and knows how it works can shed some light here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stick to this article 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140(v=sql.105).aspx

and here is the article for MS AS 2014

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx

of course there is also an article for MS AS 2012

Some time ago X4R did not support Windows-Authentication, meaning that either you have to configure IIS for anonymous access (I would not do this) or you have to provide a user and a pwd within your R script

Then the connection will work.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You need a URL for the connection, and you've given what looks like a windows network address.

This [page](http://wiki.openi.org/installation/setup-xmla-interface-for-olap-servers) has some info on setting up xmla access in various servers, and gives some examples URLs which should follow the same pattern as you need. Specifically you will probably need the IP name or address of the server.

Comment: it is a network address. Using that address as server address, I was able to connect to cube in Excel.

Comment: I can access the server in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Is it possible to get the url from there?

Comment: Once you've got the IP name or address of the server (what you have is something like a NetBIOS domain\\name) then try sticking it in  `http://ip-name-here/olap/msmdpump.dll` in a web browser and see if it connects. Or ask the server admin.